# Align text and pulldown menu in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Any suggestions how to align the text and pulldown into one line? Also in line with the search box on the right side of the page?

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <form id="limit" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">Bekijk
            <select class="form-control" id="limit" name="limit" onchange="this.form.submit()">
              <option <?php if($limit == '10') { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="10">10</option>
              <option <?php if ($limit == '25') { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="25">25</option>
              <option <?php if ($limit == '50') { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="50">50</option>
              <option <?php if ($limit == '100') { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="100">100</option>
            </select>
            records
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" readonly="readonly">

    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
    <form id="search" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" onclick="document.forms.search.submit()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" onkeydown="submit_search()">
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="limit" name="limit" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>" readonly="readonly">

    </form>
</div>
```

Current layout
[image]

Layout goal
[image]

Comment: Did you try `display:inline-block` on the `<select>` element?

Comment: That is only increasing the width of the `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div class="form-inline">` instead of `<div class="form-group">`